# Normal direction at a point in 3D coordinate system

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, rotational-dynamics, vectors, collision

I was reading [this article](https://www.euclideanspace.com/physics/dynamics/collision/threed/index.htm) and they said

> Determine the collision point and the normal direction at this point.

Can someone help understand this?

Answer (score 1):

The article is concerned with shaped objects in collision; when two
objects touch, the first-contact point is on the curved surface of
both objects, and (unless the surfaces are very un-smooth) that point
on each surface corresponds to a local direction perpendicular
to the surface(s) at that point.  It is that direction (and the
location of the contact) that determine how, if at all, the
objects will change their spin as they come away from the collision.

A 'normal' is a vector (usually a unit vector) which is perpendicular
to a surface, and can be generated by a cross product of non-parallel
vectors in that surface, at that point.

Comment: If a ball hits the ground how the normal vector at that point would be  ?

Comment: The vector from the center of the ball and the collison point is r which is the radius of the ball , and the vector from the center of earth and the collision point is the radius of earth and those two radius are prependicular to ground surface so how the cross product would be ?

Comment: @Zaak If 'the ground' is horizontal, the normal vector points straight UP.  A cross product from surface-N to surface-W points in this direction, if those N and W directions are in the horizontal plane.  The patch on the ball that contacts the Earth is in the same horizontal plane, so it has the same normal.  Convention may apply to the SIGN of the normal (ball opposite Earth)